# Problem Installing Matlab 2012a in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, matlab

The following problem is occurring while starting installation:

`sudo /media/MATHWORKS_R2012A/install -glnx86 -v

[sudo] password for kittu:

sudo: /media/MATHWORKS_R2012A/install: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

First, in the terminal change directory to the MATHWORKS_R2012A folder.

`cd /media/MATHWORKS_R2012A`

Then change the permission on the installer so that root can execute it.

`sudo chmod +x ./install`

Now you can run the installer. I'm not sure if you need the extra options you have in your question or not, but it will look like this:

`sudo ./install`